# How do I format a date in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to meet the condition that the purchase date is before 2012 and I can't figure out how to format my SQL code to get this right.

My current code:

```
SELECT g.GameName, p.GameID, g.GameID 
FROM games g, purchases p 
WHERE p.GameID = g.GameID
AND p.DatePurchase < 2012-01-01
```

And the database is formatted in the same was (as in '2012-06-15') but when I run this code it runs but I get 0 results.

Comment: use `''` around date. or it would be treated as numeric and `2012-01-01` would result in 2010 and hence you don't get a result.

Comment: did you try to put the date in single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT g.GameName, p.GameID, g.GameID 
FROM games g, purchases p 
WHERE p.GameID = g.GameID
AND p.DatePurchase < '2012-01-01'
```

If the date stored in the database is in datetime format, then just cast it as Date. Please look at the below code

```
   SELECT g.GameName, p.GameID, g.GameID 
   FROM games g, purchases p 
   WHERE p.GameID = g.GameID
   AND CAST(p.DatePurchase AS DATE) < '2012-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare year you can always use `MySQL` `YEAR` function.

```
SELECT g.GameName, p.GameID, g.GameID 
FROM games g, purchases p 
WHERE p.GameID = g.GameID
AND YEAR(p.DatePurchase) < '2012'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the date value isn't quoted, so it's interpreted as an arithmetic expression `2012 - 1 - 1`, i.e. `2010`.

This is easily fixed:

```
... AND p.DatePurchase < '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.